# Error converting data type varchar to numeric. For showing Data

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am doing a website that when I click for a specific button it will show data or status. But when I click it this Error converting data type varchar to numeric appears.

Here is my code

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
    Try
        ds = GetDataSet2("dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, last_check), 0) as DateMonthly, SUM((convert(decimal(5,2), left(duration, 3))))/count(*) as AverageMonthly", "tblServices_Status AS TSES, tblWeb_Apps as TWA", "TSES.web_apps_id = TWA.web_apps_id AND TWA.web_apps_id = '" & appid & "' AND MONTH(last_check) = MONTH(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate())) AND YEAR(last_check) = YEAR(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate()))", "dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, last_check), 0)", "dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, last_check), 0)")
        For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            lblAppAveMonthly.Text = Format(Val(dr("AverageMonthly")), "0.00") + "s"
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        ds.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Thank you very much

here is the code for my GetDataSet2

```
    Public Shared Function GetDataSet2(ByVal columnname As String, ByVal databasename As String, ByVal condition As String, ByVal columngroup As String, ByVal columnorder As String) As DataSet
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection()
    conn = getConn()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim query As String

    Try
        If condition = "" Then
            condition = "1 = 1"
        End If

        query = "SELECT " & columnname & "  FROM " & databasename & " WHERE " & condition & " GROUP BY " & columngroup & " ORDER BY " & columnorder &""

        Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter(query, conn)

        sda.Fill(ds)

        sda.Dispose()
    Catch oError As Exception
        Throw oError
    Finally
        If conn.State Then conn.Close()
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
    Return ds
End Function
```

Comment: Hi @arkeysi could you show your function GetDataSet2 on Ask Question content ?

Comment: We don't know what happens in GetDataSet2 (as @willie already pointed out). This particular error comes from your database telling you that you are trying to use an alphanumeric (varchar/string) value where a numeric is REQUIRED. I am going to venture a guess and say the problem is with this code: `SUM((convert(decimal(5,2), left(duration, 3))))/count(*) as AverageMonthly` but this pretty hard to solve without knowing a) what that GetDateSet2 function really does and b) the structure of your tables and data inside of them.

Comment: [Edit] your post to add more code details.  Code does not format in comments

Comment: Hi @arkeysi can you show your " query" detail  by using break point with F11 , in my opinion it should be very easy to look out question on step by step , by the way you can show you error message to us , thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only likely candidate I see for causing this error is in this bit:

```
SUM((convert(decimal(5,2), left(duration, 3))))/count(*) as AverageMonthly
```

Query your `duration` column for any rows where the first 3 characters could not be converted to a decimal(5,2) datatype.

If you have SQL Server 2012 or higher, the TRY_PARSE() function would be highly useful here.